# Защита файла от несканкционированного доступа

Tags: c#

Было реализовано следующее задание: пользователь вводит логин и пароль, проверяется совпадение введённых данных с данными в текстовом документе. Таким образом если злоумышленник получит доступ к текстовому файлу то он сможет изменить пароль на известный лишь ему. Вопрос в том, какими способами можно обезопасить программу чтобы это предотвратить? Уже есть ответ хэшированием, нужны ещё хорошие способы- как защитить текстовый файл.

Comment: Защитить от чего? Какая ваша модель угроз? Без этого анализировать не имеет смысла. Пример: если злоумышленник имеет доступ к программе, он может просто дизассемблировать её и отключить в ней кусок, проверяющий данные на правильность. Или он может подменить хэш на другой, подходящий к заранее выбранному злоумышленником паролю.

Answer (score 1):

Шифровать файл (юзать нестандартный хэш), а прогу обфусцировать.